# Access properties file within Class Library

Tags: c#, properties

I am currently working on a C# project where I have 3 separate projects within VS2010. 2 of the projects are different types of executable programs and the 3rd project is a C# class library.

I have created a properties file within the class library that the 2 executable programs needs to access to save the settings within this property file.

How do I access the properties file inside the class library from the other projects.

The other projects have the Class Library references and I have tried doing MyLibrary.Properties, but it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add a reference to the class library?

For every project (not the library) right click on References -> Add Reference -> Under projects double click on the library (Mylibrary.Properties). This will add the library to the project. See if this solves your problem.